# Filtering data based on matching string after grouping in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to group by `Id` and `Vehicle` and then return only vehicles whose Auction have only 'Merged Salvage' and 'Merged Salvage API' values. Vehicles who have Auction other than these two types will get filtered out. How can I achieve this?

Data:

```
Id      Vehicle            Auction      Offer
10  1984 Porsche 944     Copart             100
10  1984 Porsche 944     Merged Salvage     200
10  1984 Porsche 944     IAA                140
11  2000 Chevrolet G3500 Copart              80
11  2000 Chevrolet G3500 Merged Salvage     100
11  2000 Chevrolet G3500 Merged Salvage API 120
11  2000 Chevrolet G3500 SVP                130
12  2001 Honda CRV       Merged Salvage      50
12  2001 Honda CRV       Merged Salvage API 100
```

Expected output:

```
Id      Vehicle            Auction      Offer
12  2001 Honda CRV       Merged Salvage      50
12  2001 Honda CRV       Merged Salvage API 100
```

Comment: Can you please show your attempts at solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a `df.groupby` operation, followed by `dfGroupBy.transform` should do it:

```
In [1097]: status = ['Merged Salvage', 'Merged Salvage API']

In [1098]: df[df.groupby(['Id', 'Vehicle']).Auction\
                 .transform(lambda x: x.isin(status).min())]
Out[1098]: 
   Id         Vehicle             Auction  Offer
7  12  2001 Honda CRV      Merged Salvage     50
8  12  2001 Honda CRV  Merged Salvage API    100
```

The predicate checks for the status using `pd.Series.isin`.